# What are possible learning libraries giving probability scores for multi-class classification labels?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Suppose I have a data with 4 labels. I want to model a classifiers that is able to give probability values to those 4 labels where sum of the values should be 1. Is there any known ML library that is available for doing that ?

Answer (score -1):

I guess most of the multi-class classifiers could return probabilities in prediction mode. For example, in the case of the scikit [OneVsRest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) classifier there is the "predict_proba(X)" method.

Comment: I know that function but it is not available in most of the linear classifiers since it requires log loss function to be in use.

Comment: In my case I've used sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression classifier - everything worked well!
BTW, it's not recommended to use true linear models for classification: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html#classification